# How to add google AdSense to Php Laravel?

Tags: laravel, adsense

I can't add google AdSense to Laravel. Tried adding a package as well but didn't work? Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to creat adsense account. login and add new site. Provide the url and it will give you a script to put in side head tag like this.

```
<script async 
  src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca- 
  pub-123456789123456"
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

once you place the script then it will be verified. and you can create adds and templates to show ads. Hope this helps.

Comment: When will it be verified? Does it take time because I added the AdSense inside the head tag a week ago and I still can't see any changes?

Comment: Normally it may take 2 to 3 dyas. If your website has meet the criteria. you can share  your website link to me for refrence. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead putting `<script>` in `<head>`, it's faster to be verified if you upload the `ads.txt` file into the server Laravel's `public/` folder.